# New CMake version results in strange command lines and warnings

Tags: cmake, version, ubuntu-20.04

I've been building a (vendor supplied) package with CMake for about a year now under Ubuntu-18.04-LTS and 20.04-LTS, but it seems that after a recent upgrade (cmake version 3.23.1) something has changed which is giving many weird anomalies. I'm wondering if any of the following look familiar and if there's an easy fix?

```
CMake Warning:
  Ignoring extra path from command line:
  "Export compile commands"
```

I can tell that this is because I'm getting a `build.make` file generated that contains

```
-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON CACHE INTERNAL FORCE "Export compile commands"
```

which in turn is coming from this snippet in `default.cmake`:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON
    CACHE INTERNAL FORCE
    "Export compile commands")
```

but what I can't figure out (being an intimidated novice CMake user) is why this recently stopped working normally and started giving these warning messages. I could ignore the warnings but I don't know for certain that other bad things aren't happening under the hood as well.

Is there something I can do (short of waiting for the vendor to release a fix, who knows when that might happen) that will get my builds working normally again?

Comment: Try changing it to `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON CACHE INTERNAL "Export compile commands")`

Answer (score 1):

`FORCE` is the last parameter of the `set` command.

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON
    CACHE INTERNAL FORCE
    "Export compile commands")
```

creates a cache variable with documentation `"FORCE"` and list one additional parameter `"Export compile commands"` which does not match the [pattern of `set(CACHE)` usage](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html):

> ```
> set(<variable> <value>... CACHE <type> <docstring> [FORCE])
> ```

Change the snippet to

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON
    CACHE INTERNAL
    "Export compile commands" FORCE)
```

and the warning should be fixed. You may also remove `FORCE` entirely, since `FORCE` is implied by type `INTERNAL`.

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON
    CACHE INTERNAL
    "Export compile commands")
```